# How to get border-radius on <tr> on tr:hover?

Tags: html, css

First I have a big `<div class="content">` it contains the `<table>`, what I want is :

- The table (or the content) needs a border-radius (10px)
- When passing cursor on every row (not `<table>` but just `<tr>` : background-color changes (it's okay), but the the content needs to keep the border-radius (it's not okay for now -> this is my question )

How to make the border-radius of the `<div class=content">` shown (now the tr is "overriding it and the border-radius disappears on hover)

Here is a simple script (the yellow color needs to be same as the gray one when hover = same width same border-radius)

```css
.content{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  border-radius:10px;
  background-color:gray;
}

table{
  width:100%;
  cursor:pointer;
}

tr{
  width:100%;
  border-radius:10px !important;
}

table tr:hover{
  background-color:gold;
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<table>
<tr>
  <td>hello</td>
  <td>world</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`border-radius` needs to be applied to the `td` element.

Use the `:first-child` and `:last-child` selectors to apply the border radius.

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
tr {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px !important;
}
table tr:hover {
  background-color: gold;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
table tr:hover td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
table tr:hover td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>hello</td>
      <td>world</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing! Nice one!

Comment: This needs prefixes for some browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply the `border-radius` to your `td` tags, rather than your `tr` tags. Assuming you have multiple rows in your table, each containing multiple cells, you will need to set apply a `border-radius` to four different cells:

- The top left of the first cell of the first row,
- The top right of the last cell of the first row,
- The bottom left of the first cell of the last row, and,
- The bottom right of the last cell of the last row.

Here's how you would do so:

```css
table{
  background:gray;
  border-radius:10px;
  width:100%;
}
tr:hover>td{
  background:gold;
}
tr:first-child>td:first-child{
  border-top-left-radius:10px;
}
tr:first-child>td:last-child{
  border-top-right-radius:10px;
}
tr:last-child>td:first-child{
  border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
}
tr:last-child>td:last-child{
  border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td>Ipsum</td>
      <td>Dolor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td>Ipsum</td>
      <td>Dolor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td>Ipsum</td>
      <td>Dolor</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need also `border-radius` on `td` that's why that color is going over the radius of the tr

I've put `border-top-left-radius` and `border-bottom-left-radius` on the first `td` and `border-top-right-radius` and `border-bottom-right-radius` on the last `td`

let me know if it helps

```css
.content{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  border-radius:10px;
  background-color:gray;
}

table{
  width:100%;
  cursor:pointer;
}

tr{
  width:100%;
  border-radius:10px !important;
}
td:last-child {
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
td:first-child{
   -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
   border-top-left-radius: 10px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

table tr:hover{
  background-color:gold;
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<table>
<tr>
  <td>hello</td>
  <td>world</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content">
<table>
<tr>
  <td>hello</td>
  <td>world</td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.content{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  border-radius:10px;
  background-color:gray;
}

table{
  width:100%;
  cursor:pointer;
}

tr:first-child td:first-child { border-top-left-radius: 10px; }
tr:first-child td:last-child { border-top-right-radius: 10px; }
tr:last-child td:first-child { border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; }
tr:last-child td:last-child { border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; }

table tr:hover{
  background-color:gold;
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

Comment: Add your code here first and add the bottom, add the link to the fiddle. Right now it is in low quality review.

Comment: @Adi : `tr:first-child td:first-child` would work only for first row - first column. What if there are multiple rows ?

Comment: Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eradi_singh/05mzwaLp/ then you will came to know why i answered that